# How to retrieve client cert from android cert store

Tags: android, keystore, android-keystore

I have created a client cert using self signed root CA, Installed the **clientcert.p12** file in android  device.

I need to use the cert in my app, the following code piece I have tried.

```
 KeyStore store = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
            if (store != null) 
            {

                store.load(null, new String("the keystore password").toCharArray());
                Log.i("BIRAJENDU", "CERT CHECK" + "Type: "+ store.getType()+ " Size: " +store.size());

                Enumeration<String> aliases = store.aliases();
                if (!aliases.hasMoreElements()) {
                        Log.i("BIRAJENDU", "No cert found");
                 }
```

}

I am always getting store.size() as zero.

But if I use  `KeyStore store = KeyStore.getInstance("AndroidCAStore");` , I am getting proper store size. But here my need is to find **PKCS12** store.

Answer (score -1):

You'll need to use the Android KeyChain (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/security/KeyChain.html).

Comment: Yes this info was useful to find the private key. But my requirement is not access all PKCS cert chain with out user interventions, In the above KeyChain approach, I need to call choosePrivateKeyAlias(). This is pooping up cert select system dialog. My use case does not allow this.

Comment: In that case, you need to import the certificate into the app, or your app needs to be the Device Owner or Profile Owner component which imported the certificate into the device.

Comment: My App is not a MDM app, So I don't think I can make it device owner or profile owner app.

Comment: In that case, you need to import the certificate straight into the app.

Comment: In My case the certificate suppose to be installed by MDM, My app need to read and validate. Just a thought, whether MDM can send the certificate to my app? Not sure about this feature with MDM.

Comment: I want to do this exact thing. @Birajendu Did you find a way?